# I am trying to upload a file to google drive using python and Drive API from google Cloud. But it's credentials expires after sometime. what to do?

Tags: python-3.x, google-oauth, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I am using python to upload files to my google drive, just a simple script. It works fine for sometimes but after sometimes the credentials which I generated expires. Is there as way I can make those credentials not to expire for life time. I also looked on to some YouTube videos who were suggesting something called refresh token. But I don't know how to generate and use them in my script.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code. They python client library is handling most of this for you.  It is creating the refresh token and storing it in your token pickle most likely

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that sometime means seven days.

This is because as stated in [oauth2#expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

Go to google could console for your project. Under the Ouath2 consent screen and set your project to production.  Your refresh tokens will stop expiring.